# "Start a bounty" link easily overlooked below comments

Tags: feature-request, bounties

The "start a bounty" link currently is shown below the comments:

> [image]

where it is easily overlooked since it is expected at the bottom of the question, above the comments.

Comment: hmm... it's there, but it's below comments.

Comment: @Oded It just wasn't where it was expected, can you repro that it appears below the comments?

Comment: That's where it's been for years... perhaps make this into a feature request then?

Comment: @Oded Strange. I always thought it was above them.